# Undefined id property on td object when accessed through rows/cells collection

Tags: javascript, dom

What is it I am doing wrong here:

When I try to use the getttribute['id'] method on a TableCell object that I get from iterating through a tables rows/cells it returns undefined:

```
var rows = document.getElementById["table"].rows;
var cells;
for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
 cells = rows[i].cells
 for(var j=0; j < cells.length; j++) {
  alert(cells[j].innerHTML); //returns Cell1
  alert(cells[j].getAttribute["id"]); //returns undefined
  alert(document.getElementById["c1"].innerHTML); //returns Cell1

 }
}
```

This is example HTML:

```
    <table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td id="c1">Cell1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Question is why does the getAttribute method return undefined for all attributes when accessed through cells[j]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.getAttribute)** is a method and you are using it as an indexer

Use

```
alert(cells[j].getAttribute("id"));
```

Also replace

```
document.getElementById["table"].rows;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("table").rows;
```

and

```
document.getElementById["c1"].innerHTML
```

with

```
document.getElementById("c1").innerHTML
```

**[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById)** is also a method.

Answer (score 1):

You are using square brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()` in calls to `getElementById` and `getAttribute`

```
//change

getElementById["table"]
getAttribute["id"]
getElementById["c1"]

//to

getElementById("table")
getAttribute("id")
getElementById("c1")

//Respectively.
```

Comment: Yes that's true, it is a method! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but `getAttribute` doesn't like the id attribute. Use `cells[j].id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use cells[j].id to get the id of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can use the getAttribute method:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("sec")[0].getAttribute("id")
```

Here I'll get back `s1` for a tag like `<sec id="s1">`.